# java collect streams and grouping depending on variable

Tags: java, grouping, java-stream, collect

I was given these two classes "Transaction" that has attributes Trader trader, int year, int value, long seq, and "Trader" that has attributes String name, String city.

I need to group this stream and sum only if `seq = seq + 1`:

```
    Trader raoul = new Trader("Raoul", "Cambridge");
    Trader mario = new Trader("Mario","Milan");
    Trader alan = new Trader("Alan","Cambridge");
    Trader brian = new Trader("Brian","Cambridge");

    List<Transaction> transactions = Arrays.asList(
        new Transaction(brian, 2012, 300, 1), 
        new Transaction(raoul, 2012, 1000, 2),
        new Transaction(raoul, 2012, 400, 13),
        new Transaction(mario, 2012, 710, 14),  
        new Transaction(mario, 2012, 700, 94),
        new Transaction(alan, 2012, 950, 95)
    );
```

How can I achieve this please:

```
{Trader:Brian in Cambridge, year: 2012, value:1300, seq:1}, {Trader:Raoul in Cambridge, year: 2012, value:1110, seq:13}, {Trader:Mario in Milan, year: 2012, value:1650, seq:94}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Do you mean you want to group elements based on the seq ? You'd group the first two transactions because  2 = 1 + 1 ?

Comment: Yes based on seq. Group the first two (1,2) and (13,14) and (94,95) and so on..

Comment: It seems a crazy requirement. Would you group 3 transactions with seq = {1,2,3} and so on ?

Comment: no just two transaction, not more. they go in a pair - just two elements not 3.

Comment: Can you have sequence numbers 1, 2, 7, 13, 14, with transaction 7 processed differently, or are they guaranteed to be in pairs? Also, could the sequence numbers be out of order?

Comment: the fact that you are saying `previous` and `stream` is already a bit troublesome. but this is a fairly easy task for a custom collector...

Comment: for the sequence numbers 1, 2, 7, 13, 14, it should be (1,2), (7) and (13,14) because 7 doesn't have any matching 7+1 record.

Answer (score 0):

An example solution:

```
Stream.concat(
    transactions.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(transaction -> transaction.seq / 2 ))
    .entrySet().stream(),

    transactions.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(transaction -> (transaction.seq + 1) / 2))
    .entrySet().stream()

    )
    .filter(elem -> elem.getValue().size() == 2)
    .map(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().reduce((left, right) -> new Transaction(left.trader, left.year, left.value + right.value, Long.min(left.seq, right.seq))).get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The above code:

1. Groups the transactions based on their `seq` number divided by two (since in your example, the sequence for a pair of transactions might start both with an even and with an odd number, we need to do it twice, once rounding the division result up, and once down)
2. Filters out mismatched values (those that were not matched with a consecutive transaction in either of the above two maps)
3. Concatenates the result into a single stream, discarding the map keys
4. Maps the pairs of transaction into a single transaction representing the aggregate state of the original transactions

Note that the above could be further simplified if the sequences for the pairs of transactions always started with an odd number

Comment: thanks, I'm currently trying to implement accept function for reduce and then putting condition on the sequence number if equal to previous seq number +1.